# How to display different text when user change menu option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, rails-i18n

I am checking this [example](https://github.com/recurser/jquery-i18n/blob/master/examples/index.html).

Actually, it changes the text when user clicks the button (in other language ).

But what if user has 3 different languages? (some type of menu option) and on change the option it changes the text.

I have **name**(in english) but I want to change it to spanish and german also on click. How can I do it?

In example there is a toggle for languages when user clicks the button. If he wants to switch between three or four language - how do implement such a feature?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it. There is **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/samosfator/yBM69/)**.

Firstly, create new button with different id in your HTML.

1. `<input type='button' id='translate_button2' value='Internationalize to Russian!'>`
2. Then, you have to make some changes in provided javascript. Create new Object with strings translated to third language. Name it `i18n_dict2`, for example. Simply copy everything from `i18n_dict` and just translate needed strings.
3. And the last you should do is to define event handler to second button(code that will run after click to button). Copy everything inside `$('input#translate_button').click(function (event) {` and paste after it. But don't forget to change `input#translate_button` to `input#translate_button2`(it's id of your newly created button).
4. And one more. You have to make your new object avaiable inside second event handler. Just insert `$.i18n.setDictionary(i18n_dict2);` inside `$('input#translate_button').click(function (event) {`